# Collision detection against player and blocks in the map

Tags: python, pygame

I made a game map like this

```
class Game_map:
    def __init__(self):
        self.land = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\final game\land.png").convert()
        self.height = 200
        self.width = 200
        self.land = pygame.transform.scale(self.land, (420,  250))
        self.land.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

        self.map_width = 6000
        self.map_height = 2000

        # 0 = emepty
        # 1 = land

        self.layout = [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]]



    def draw_map(self):
        y = 0
        for layer in self.layout:
            x = 0
            for land in layer:
                if land == 1:
                    D.blit(self.land, (x * 400 - scroll[0],  y * 250 - scroll[1]))

                if land == 0:
                    pass

                x += 1
            y += 1




game_map = Game_map()
```

I have a player class as well with `self.x`, `self.y`, `self.width` and `self.height` . How would i implement collision detection with this? My  initial idea was that i would use `self.x` and `self.y` in the `draw_map()` function so that i could later check for collisions like this

```
 def draw_map(self):
        for layer in self.layout:
            for land in layer:
                if land == 1:
                    D.blit(self.land, (self.x * 400 - scroll[0], self. y * 250 - scroll[1]))

                if land == 0:
                    pass

                x += 1
            y += 1
```

But when i do this, nothing gets drawn on the screen. I also tried adding `x` and `y` values in the original `draw_map` function mentioned above to a list and detect collision with that but it got really messy and didnt work. Is there any other way to do collision detection ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward method is to find the collisions of the player rectangle and the obstacle rectangles.

Create a list of the field indices of all obstacles:

```py
obstacles = [(i, j) for i in range(len(game_map.layout))
                    for j in range(len(game_map.layout[i]))
                    if game_map.layout[i][j] == 1]
```

Setup a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for the player:

```py
player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
```

Use [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to find the collisions of the player and the obstacles:

```py
hit = [obj for obj in obstacles
           if player_rect.colliderect(
               pygame.Rect(obj[0]*400-scroll[0], obj[1]*250-scroll[1], 400, 250))]

if any(hit):
    print("hit")
```

---

The more tricky by far more efficient method is to compute the field indices for the 4 corners of the player rectangle and to evaluate if one of the corners is in a field with an obstacle.

Setup the player rectangle:

```py
player_rect = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
```

Compute the coordinates for corners of the rectangle:

```py
player_corners = [player_rect.topleft, player_rect.topright, 
                  player_rect.bottomleft, player_rect.bottomright]
```

Compute the field indices, where the corner points are on:

```py
corner_indices = [((p[0]+scroll[0])//400, (p[1]+scroll[1])//250) for p in player_corners]
```

Evaluate if any of the field contains an obstacle:

```py
hit = [ind for ind in corner_indices if game_map.layout[ind[0]][ind[1]]]

if (any(hit)):
    print("hit")
```